# How to close realm object in android

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to check if any realm object is in transaction, so that I can remove entire DB. But this statement always `returns false`.  `Realm.getDefaultInstances().isClose()`  where I have done wrong. someone explain me please.

```
 if(!Realm.getDefaultInstances().isInTransaction()){

    Realm.getDefaultInstances().close();
    if(Realm.getDefaultInstances().isClosed()){
       Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction(){
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        realm.deleteAll();

                        realm.close();

                    }
                });

          }
    }
```

Comment: Quite not sure though check the method name ?
 Realm.getDefaultInstances().isClose() or Realm.getDefaultInstance().isClosed()

Comment: @Raghavendra, Thanks for informing & I haved updated the code.

Comment: `Realm.getDefaultInstances()` there is no such thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm instances are reference counted, so calling `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` before each method will increase that count to at least 4 in your example, meaning that you need to call `.close()` 4 times as well.

Note, that calling `close()` inside a transaction lambda will cause the transaction to not be committed. The close has to be on the outside.

I would highly recommend reading these two sections about controlling the Realm life cycle:

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realms

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realm-instance-lifecycle

Comment: opening Realm instances with Realm.getDefaultInstance() that they never close anywhere?

Comment: @Dedeepthika close after transaction is completed

Answer (score 3):

```
try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
        realm.deleteAll();
    }); 
} // <-- auto-close
```

But you need to call `close()` for each `getInstance()` call.

Comment: I have exactly used the same procedure for calling realm i think it must be 500 places. but i didnot use realm.close for each transaction. can you tell me wht to do ?

Comment: `getInstance` increments a refcount. You should make sure you know exactly when you open an instance and where you need to close it.